# Json devuelve /Date(12355200000)/

Tags: php, json

Recibo una fecha en este formato: /Date(12355200000)/ y quiero pasarlo a este otro: año/mes/dia.

Pero no veo forma de como hacerlo, no se que formato es (viene de un json).

Alguien me podría ayudar?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿De dónde viene?

Comment: Si no me equivoco, ese formato de fecha es en milisegundos. Así que deberías convertir los milisegundos al formato que requieras. Si tienes más dudas, pues deja saber.

Comment: Viene de una api, creo que es un formato json de microsoft o algo así. Debe de ser algo que hacen con .net, pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: Llamo a la API con el HttpClient de symfony y en la respuesta json los campos fecha aparecen así

Comment: Muestra el código en el que recibes y manejas el dato.

Comment: Te falta agregar el [ejemplo-minimo-verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de tu codgo, como dice @A.Cedano

Comment: Prueba con `echo date('Y/m/d',12355200000/1000)`.

Comment: Pienso que antes de improvisar una respuesta, es importante conocer el formato del origen del dato, de otra forma estaríamos adivinando. La mayoría de lenguajes de programación manejan las fechas de este tipo de manera diferente.

Comment: De verdad que si tuviera mas datos, los hubiera puesto.
El codigo no tiene mas misterio, es una llamada con el httpCliente de symfony:

$response = $this->client->request pasandole la cabecera application/json y recogiendolo asi $datos = $response->toArray();